# Connect function to pictures displayed from a PC folder

Tags: javascript, html, image, function

I'm pretty new to JS and programming altogether so I'm sorry in advance if the explanation is a little sloppy, but I'll try to make it as clear as possible.

So what I'm trying to do is have a JS code that reads and displays (in an HTML page) photos from a PC folder, makes them clickable and on the click it redirects you to a page with the same photo but in high resolution.

Now, I have this piece of code that displays the said pictures, but the thing is I don't seem to be able to figure out how to "connect" it to the pictures and make them clickable. What makes it more difficult is that I'm trying to make all of this code dynamic (as you can see I've done in the below code), so I would like not to have any hardcoded titles of pictures and so on.

```
var index = 1;
var tempImg = new Image();
tempImg.onload = function(){
   appendImage();
}
var tryLoadImage = function(index){
   tempImg.src = 'img/' + index + '.jpg';
}
var appendImage = function(){
   var img = document.createElement('img');
   img.src = tempImg.src;
   document.body.appendChild(img)
   tryLoadImage(index++);
}
tryLoadImage(index);
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: can you also show the html you're using?

Comment: I'm trying to generate everything from the JS code, my HTML only has the basic things: link tag to css and script tag to JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your images clickable by adding an `onclick` function to them. Try something like this:

```
var appendImage = function(){
   var img = document.createElement('img');
   img.src = tempImg.src;

   img.onclick = e => {
      // do something you want to show the full picture like this maybe
      var el = document.getElementById("fullpictureid");
      if (el && e.target.src) {
         el.src = e.target.src;
         // so that it sets "src" in <img id="fullpictureid"> for example 
      }
   };
   document.body.appendChild(img)
   tryLoadImage(index++);
}
```